# Delete Rows that are variable in Xlwings

Tags: python, rows, xlwings

Working on Python with Xlwings environment I am struggling to find a way to delete rows in an excel Spreadsheet thatare mentioned as variables, which in this instance are the following:

```
S_Headers.row + 1

RR.Row
```

These two variables are numbers, derived from the row number of two ranges in the workbook. What I basically need to do is:

1. Select rows comprised between the two variables;
2. Delete them;
3. Insert an equal number of new rows

I understand this can be done by inputing numbers as per below:

```
sht.range('100:150').api.Delete(DeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp)
```

However I am struggling to find a solution when I can only use variables rather than numbers. Any help is massively appreciated!